# SCRAM failure: bad auth : authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

I am having this issue on local development:

```
Error occurred during query execution:
ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: AuthenticationFailed { user: "SCRAM failure: bad auth : authentication failed" }, transient: false })
    at async Page (./app/dashboard/[...folder]/page.tsx:49:16)
digest: "1029893487"
 ⨯ PrismaClientUnknownRequestError:
Invalid `prisma.cafe.findUnique()` invocation:
```

this error has been appeared after deploying to vercel. Problem with local development but everything is as expected on deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Tyler for your answer the error was from local env file I found that I didn't updated my mongo url from .env.local

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, eventually I ended up creating a new user under the MongoDB Atlas database users and that seemed to fix it.

Another thing to note is that I had numbers in my original username, and I took them out for the new user (not sure if that is what fixed it or not).